# password_hash() In PHP While Setting The Algorithm as '1'

Tags: php, algorithm, hash

I came across PHP code where the password_hash was using as following:

```
password_hash($Password, 1, $Options);
```

I searched online for what the "1" corresponds to and I couldn't find anything useful. I tried to use the function locally with the same parameters and I noticed that every time I run the script, a new hash gets generated which makes me think that the "1" doesn't mean a specific hashing algorithm. However all the hashes generated had that form:

```
$2y$10$8sYYAM4E9hQI6NvKEghsl.OE.5zdhVs5NN0OiUT6chEbhP9xKTPTe
$2y$10$qaj/qcnQU2XufH4Koy0zAeEV1oJRGu5Kov1z0ycKWCuH0pQtQAJdK
```

I used multiple hash identifiers and as expected couldn't reach the type of the hash. Apparently my question is: Does "1" means to randomly use hashing algorithms that are supported by php? and if so, why do all the hashes generated start with "$2y$10$"?

Comment: The value of `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` is `1`.

Comment: The manual is pretty clear (http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) - the 1 represents an enumerated value for the hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read [from the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), there are two constants for the algorithm, `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` and `PASSWORD_BCRYPT`. 
The first refers to the default/recommended algorithm, and is subject to change, while the second one explicitly refers to the BCrypt algorithm.

They both have the value `1` as BCrypt is currently the only supported encryption algorithm for `password_hash`. This also explains the string prefix you mentioned:

> [PASSWORD_BCRYPT] will produce a standard crypt() compatible hash using the "$2y$"
>   identifier.

So, passing `1` has the same effect as using the constants, and your confusion explains exactly why you should use constants instead of [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants). ;)

Checking the value of a constant can of course simply be done by displaying it using `echo` or `var_dump`:

```
echo PASSWORD_BCRYPT
```

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the [official docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) a hash is generated using the following code

```
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
```

The second parater "algo":

> A password algorithm constant denoting the algorithm to use when hashing the password.

It's rather simple to check what this constant contain

```
var_dump(PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // int(1)
```

Hence your code uses PASSWORD_DEFAULT, which in all PHP versions so far has been Bcrypt